# How can I make a custom deserializer for TcpNetClientConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've a TCP server in python, who have to send XML documents, into strings like that :

```
<MSG_IVEF><Header MsgRefId="" Version="0.2.5">{1,1}</Header><Body>{1,1}</Body></MSG_IVEF>
```

And I have TCP Client, with Spring Integration, implemented with a `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` and I need to set a custom deserializer to read on the TCP.

How can i make a custom one like the `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` ? For example, if I want to have same but with `<MSG_IVEF>` and `</MSG_IVEF>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it is an XML, I wouldn't look to the `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` logic. Because your `MSG_IVEF` is a root tag of the XML document, and `STX/ETX` bytes are excluded from the target message after deserialization. You definitely don't want to loose root tag in your document.

Not sure what is the problem on your client and server to finish sending the XML document with some standard delimiter, like provided one via `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer`. There is also `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` which can be customized with any arbitrary byte to delimiter packages on the wire.

Comment: You're right, I don't want to loose root tag in my document. There is no problem to send XML with standard delimiter (CRLF), or with others, but I can't configure the server, the final spring application need to be configurable with the delimiter, so in client side.